# Adriod full screen background images

Tags: android, css

I am developing a site that is using CSS animations for a background slider. There seems to be a problem with the images loading on Galaxy S3. Is there something I can do to fix this? Do older phones not support animations?

Here is the site: capelos.gonzbergagency.com

And here is the demo it is based on: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS capabilities are provided by the web browser, not by the phone, verify online whether your browser version supports the CSS you used.
Also, try a modern browser like Firefox for Android or Chrome for Android, if you haven't already.

Comment: That is what I thought. It is on my bosses phone and I believe that he is using chrome for a browser. I have not actually been able to see the behavior yet, but will tomorrow. When I went out and tested it on other Android phones, it worked perfectly. @DeDee

Comment: I can tell your site works as expected with my Galaxy S3 and Chrome 39.
Always encourage your clients to update their browsers regularly for improved performance, functionality and security. It's a pain for us, developers, to include hacks for a bunch of older browsers versions because of the people like your boss.

Comment: I hear ya on that one. Thanks.